# dockerfile cmd is ignored

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I have a container running in a kubernetes pod. Commands from dockerfile of my image in this container doesn't seem to be executing during deployment/startup. The base image used has a dockerfile and I can see the output from that, but not from my image. I can see that the CMD commands are getting added during docker build, but not sure why they aren't running. I dont see any errors in the pod logs either.

```
base image
|
|_ Dockerfile

my_image
|
|_ Dockerfile.production
```

base image: Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/somescript.sh"]
```

my_image: Dockerfile.production:

```
FROM base-image
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "echo Hello from my_image!!!" ]
```

deployment manifest:

```
command:
  - bash
  - -ce
  - |
    . /entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Does the entrypoint script end with `exec "$@"`?  You mention you're running this in Kubernetes; in the Deployment manifest do you override the `command:` or `args:`?

Comment: entrypoint script ends with `exec "$@"`. I edited the post to add the `command:` from deployment manifest

Comment: Just remove the `command` entry from your deployment manifest and you should be all set. Setting `command` overrides both the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Makes sense. Just reading about it made me understand that the dockerfile entrypoint is being overridden. I wonder why it was added as `command` in the deployent manifest in the first place.